# Inserting images into JTable cell with GTKLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, icons, look-and-feel

The issue appears to be the system look and feel for Linux/Ubuntu because it works in Windows and other look and feels. I can't seem to find any way to fix this. I am currently using Ubuntu 15.10.

```
// Set my look and feel in main()
// Printed out: "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Throwable e) {}


// I set my table to render images inside the ui method. Works with every other look and feel.
ImageIcon document = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/test/documents.png")));
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"A","B"},0);
table = new JTable(model);
table.setRowHeight(document.getIconHeight());
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    model.addRow(new Object[]{document,i});

// When the L&F is set to GTK, the table will just print out Object.toString()
// For example: "javax.swing.ImageIcon@e957ef0"
```

I realize I can switch my look and feel but is there a reason this doesn't work with GTK and is there a way to get around it?

When printing out `table.getDefaultRenderer(Icon.class)` for the table it is not null but returns the following:

```
javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI$SynthTableCellRenderer[Table.cellRenderer,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@3d04a311,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

---

Using a custom default renderer works. I took the IconRenderer class from the [JTable source](http://www.javafind.net/gate.jsp?q=/library/36/java6_full_apidocs/src-html/javax/swing/JTable.IconRenderer.html#line.5369) which fixed new issues when making the custom renderer such as centering the image and no indication you selected the cell.

```
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

class IconRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer.UIResource {
    public IconRenderer() {
        super();
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        setIcon((value instanceof Icon) ? (Icon) value : null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can always add a:

```
 System.out.println( table.getDefaultRenderer(Icon.class) );
```

statement to see what is returned. I always use Icon so any kind of Icon can be displayed.

> is there a way to get around it?

If it is null then you know GTK doesn't have a default renderer so you would need to create your own Icon renderer. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information.

Comment: The default renderer for the table doesn't appear to be null and I've added the result the my question. I'll give the custom renderer a shot though.

Comment: Using a custom default renderer works, thanks! Still doesn't make sense that it wouldn't render it on its own.

Comment: @Matthew, oops you are right it will never be null because even if there is not a specific renderer for an Icon the default Object renderer will be returned which is why you are getting the toString(..) representation of the Icon. When I print out the value I get `javax.swing.JTable$IconRenderer`. It looks like you are just getting the default Object renderer since I don't see Icon in the name anywhere.